# Circular Doubly Linked List - Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to implement a circular doubly linked list but I keep getting a segmentation fault: 11 error (I believe it's because of the add and delete functions). I have no idea whether my code is even close, but I can't get past this error to test it properly. This is the code I have that I believe is involved:

(Circular_DLList.cc)

```
void Circular_DLList::add_to_tail(int a)
{
    if (is_empty()) {
        tail = new DLLNode(a);
        tail->next = tail;
    }
    else {
        tail->next = new DLLNode(a, tail->next);
    }
}

int Circular_DLList::delete_from_tail()
{
    if(!is_empty()) 
    {
        int a = tail->info;
        tail = tail->prev;
        tail->next = null;
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        tail = 0;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Any help would be fantastic, thanks.

Comment: If you get crashes (like segmentation faults) then you should run in a debugger to catch the crash "in action". That will cause the debugger to stop at the location of the crash, and let you examine values of variables and the function call stack. If the debugger doesn't stop at your code, then go up the call stack until you reach your code.

Comment: `p-> != tail` won't compile, please post your real code.

Comment: Please extract a minimal example, as per posting guidelines. It should help you focus on the problem. That said, you have broken the so-called Law of Three (or Law of Five in C++11).

Comment: Nor will the final `return a;` in `delete_from_tail` compile. Real code: There is no substitute.

Answer (score 1):

One way to find a segmentation fault is by using cout statements throughout your code and compiling and running it. If the cout statement prints something to the console then the segmentation fault happens in a line after the cout statement. Keep doing this to narrow down and locate where the line with the segmentation fault is.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one problem in your code but here is one of them.

When you add the first element, you do:

```
    tail = new DLLNode(a);
    tail->next = tail;
```

so you leave `prev` equal to `0` (BTW: use `nullptr` instead of `0`).

If you then delete the element you do:

```
    int a = tail->info;
    tail = tail->prev;  // tail becomes 0
    tail->next = null;  // Dereference 0 cause seg fault
    return a;
```

BTW: Your delete function should also delete the `DLLNode` ! Just changing pointer values isn't sufficient.

So this leads to 3 changes:

1) When adding new elements make sure to always set *both* `next`and `prev`

2) Remember to delete the `DLLNode` created with new

3) In your delete function you need a special case for checking whether the list contains exactly one element, i.e. `if (tail == tail->next) { .. delete last element .. set tail equal nullptr}`