# Deleting Node from Circular Doubly Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

I've written code to insert elements into a circular doubly linked list and to display these elements. I'm supposed to also be able to delete the tail node from the the list, as well as search the list for a specific element.

This is my working code for add and print:

```
void Circular_DLList::add_to_tail(int a)
{
    DLLNode *temp = new DLLNode;
    temp->info = a;
    if (is_empty()) {   
        tail = temp;
        temp->next = tail;
        temp->prev = tail;
    }
    else {
        temp->next = tail->next;
        temp->prev = tail;
        tail = temp;
        tail->prev->next = temp;
    }
}

void Circular_DLList::print_list()
{
    DLLNode *ptr;
    ptr = tail->next;
    do {
        cout<< ptr->info << endl;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    while(ptr != tail->next);
}
```

No matter what I write for the delete_from_tail function, it causes a segmentation fault:11. This is my attempt for the function (which throws the error).

```
int Circular_DLList::delete_from_tail()
{
    int a = tail->info;
    if(tail == tail->next) {
        delete tail;
        tail = NULL;
    }
    else {
        tail = tail->prev;
        delete tail->next;
        tail->next = NULL;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Any advice as to how to fix this would be fantastic. I've tried debugging but I can't seem to figure out the issue or where exactly it's even related to. 
Thanks

Comment: You know that concept of circular link list is actually to have no end right?

Comment: @UsamaZafar yes, but we're working with a node called tail so it was just an easy way of saying it. I'll edit the post to clarify

Comment: Does the error occur on deletion itself? I am guessing not. I think it is occuring on print after the delete right?

Comment: @UsamaZafar yep you're right, the debugger tells me it occurs when calling print which is why I'm not sure how to go about fixing it

Comment: Gimme a sec to write the answer.

Comment: When inserting (into non-empty list), you are updating 3 links. Clearly you need to update 4. Similarly on delete - to close the gap left by the removed node, two links need to be updated. Draw a picture on paper, work through the process.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I tried to add tail->prev = temp also but just got the same error. I'm not sure what else I am supposed to add

Comment: [Haven't we been here before?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36302247/circular-doubly-linked-list-segmentation-fault-11) ?

Comment: @btoohey Look at the fix it should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is pretty obvious if you look at it closely. Your delete function is breaking the circular chain of the Link list. How so? See your delete function below:

```
int Circular_DLList::delete_from_tail()
{
    int a = tail->info;
    DLLNode *temp;

    if(tail == tail->next) {
        delete tail;
        tail = NULL;
    }
    else {
        tail = tail->prev;
        delete tail->next;
        tail->next = NULL;
    }
    return a;
}
```

In the `else-condition` you are setting `tail->next = NULL` which is actually the bug and hence breaks the chain. So when print is called it assumes that circular chain is intact and hence accidently tries to access a NULL pointer which in turn leads to segmentation fault.

The Fix is very simple see the below code:

```
int Circular_DLList::delete_from_tail()
{
    int a = tail->info;
    if(tail == tail->next) {
        delete tail;
        tail = NULL;
    }
    else {
        temp = tail;
        tail = tail->prev;
        tail->next = temp->next;        // To maintain the circular chain
        tail->next->previous = tail;    // Since this element's previous also point to the node about to be deleted
        delete temp;
        temp = NULL;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you have no idea how much I appreciate this and thank you so much for explaining it too. It works perfectly!

Comment: @btoohey Glad it was helpful.